# Is the word "news" always singular?

Tags: translation, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Using Google Translate, I have this [translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXIYZ.jpg) from Russian to English:

> каковы спортивные новости?
>
> ---
>
> what are the sports news?

I know, that the word "news" is uncountable, so it is singular. Also I know, that uncountable nouns can be countable in different meanings. Are there a mistake in "Google Translate"'s variant? Or I just don't understand the rule quite well?

Comment: Do not rely on machine translation for grammar lessons.

Comment: Using Google Translate, I have this translation from Russian to English: "what are the sports news?' is it write: "are... news"? I thought that the verb " is" is necessary with the word "news".

Comment: Yes, of course I do not rely on mashine translation becouse I know grammer rules. But sometimes mashine makes us not to belive ourselves. And to have strange doubts...

Comment: And I am not at grammar lesson now.

Comment: News always takes a singular verb. For comparison, here is the Russian translation of "What is the sports news?" Что такое спортивные новости. Did you use a plural verb when you typed in the Russian text?

Comment: "Каковы спортивные новости?". Yes, I used a plural verb in the Russian text. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relies on an inaccurate machine translation between languages.

Answer (score 1):

News is a singular/non count noun and always takes a singular verb. Google Translate generally does literal word-for-word translation and cannot correct errors resulting from e.g. inputting a plural verb where the result in the output language should have a singular one.